# How to make multiple function calls on a numpy string array in one iteration?

Tags: python, arrays, python-3.x, numpy, time-complexity

Here is the code:

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> words = np.array(['   woRd ', '  amaZINg  ', '   PossiblE    '])
>>> words_fixed = np.char.lower(np.char.strip(words))
>>> words_fixed
array(['word', 'amazing', 'possible'], dtype='<U15')
```

Works perfectly fine.

As per my understanding, this code is taking a complexity of `O(2n)` since it's calling `strip` on all the elements first, returning a new `numpy array` and then calling `lower` on all elements of that array and returning another `numpy array`.
Now, I understand `O(2n)` ultimately is `O(n)`, but can it be done in `O(n)` complexity?

Is there a way to stack up multiple function calls and call them all in one iteration?

And of course, I don't want python loops because that would defeat the entire purpose of using `numpy` in the first place.

Comment: `np.vectorize` should work. Are your arrays so large you need to optimize it? I mean, you probably have enough memory for holding 2 of those arrays. Because you seem to be complaining about space complexity since time complexity will not change

Comment: Time complexity is my main issue here. And can you write an answer with the code? I'm not good with `numpy`. I'll accept it if it works.

Comment: Time complexity will always be O(n) on both cases. You will not improve on that because you still have 2 operations to run regardless if they happen inside one or two loops.

Comment: @JBernardo, `np.vectorize` is slower than plain Python iteration.  The `np.char` functions aren't any faster either.

Comment: unless you write your lower()+strip() function, I am not sure if one can improve time complexity of doing them on words first vs. on the array first. Maybe slightly due to reading from memory but lower(strip()) is still two operations on each word.

Comment: @hpaulj OP was talking about complexity which does not make sense unless he wanted to use less memory (space complexity). It seems OP just want a faster version and does not understand what time complexity is. Opposed to what you wrote on your answer, running things faster is also not changing time complexity regarding the input variable...

Comment: I understand what time complexity is. I just thought using one iteration would definitely be faster than using two for any input size.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A list of words and equivalent array:

```
In [153]: words = ['   woRd ', '  amaZINg  ', '   PossiblE    ']                         
In [154]: arr = np.array(words)
```

Your operation on the array:

```
In [155]: np.char.lower(np.char.strip(arr))                                              
Out[155]: array(['word', 'amazing', 'possible'], dtype='<U15')
```

Equivalent list comprehension:

```
In [156]: [word.strip().lower() for word in words]                                         
Out[156]: ['word', 'amazing', 'possible']
```

or using a generator inside the comprehension:

```
In [159]: [word.lower() for word in (word.strip() for word in words)]                        
Out[159]: ['word', 'amazing', 'possible']
```

Some timings:

```
In [160]: timeit [word.lower() for word in (word.strip() for word in words)]
1.33 µs ± 10.2 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000000 loops each)
In [161]: timeit [word.strip().lower() for word in words]                                  
848 ns ± 13.1 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000000 loops each)
In [162]: timeit np.char.lower(np.char.strip(arr))                                       
12.3 µs ± 143 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100000 loops each)
```

The list comprehension is fastest.  Sometimes numpy operations scale better but based on past experience with `np.char` functions, I don't think that will happen here.  The `np.char` functions are simple covers for the Python string methods.

OK, there is a way of calling two python methods on a string and iterate in `numpy`:

```
In [164]: np.frompyfunc(lambda word: word.strip().lower(),1,1)(arr)                        
Out[164]: array(['word', 'amazing', 'possible'], dtype=object)
In [165]: timeit np.frompyfunc(lambda word: word.strip().lower(),1,1)(arr)                 
6.87 µs ± 14.5 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100000 loops each)
```

Since its time is half of the chained `np.char`, you could say it cuts the time complexity from 2n to n.

`O(n)` counts only make sense if you are using the same methods of iteration.  With a mix of interpreted and compiled code as used by Python/numpy, O(n) counts of limited value.  It's more important to make optimal use of the faster-compiled code.

Comment: I tried this with 30,000 elements in words, and indeed, `[word.strip().lower() for word in words] ` is the fastest. I assumed, using `numpy` code like `np.char` would be faster since `numpy` is written in `C` which is a lot faster than `python`.